# In SonarQube I cannot view code after running the agent

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

After running sonar scanner I cannot see source code of git repository. The project and scan completes successfully. Are additional configuration parameters required other than in the configuration where the git repository is located to see the code?

Here is the configuration for the sonar-scanner

```
sonar.host.url=http://ci:9000
sonar.projectKey=Test
sonar.projectName=Test
sonar.projectVersion=0.4
sonar.sources=/opt/test/git/test/
sonar.language=java
```

[image: Sonar Dashboard]

Comment: Your screenshot does not show a dashboard. Knowing the size metrics (top-right) shown on your dashboard would be helpful. As would seeing your analysis log. Please don't put those things in a comment. Instead, [edit] your question to include them.

Comment: The problem was that I was sourcing filesystem directory and after sourcing a svn filesystem I was able to see the code. I have updated the question with a picture of code.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the svn plugin and configuring the plugin in the administration tab and checking the code into svn and checking it out it worked. It seems a simple filesystem was not enough it needed a scm configuration with meta data to import into SonarQube

[Sonar Code Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ziS.png)